# Unselect all sections when "Custom" InstType is chosen

Tags: selection, nsis

Whenever the user selects the "Custom" install type, I want to unselect all sections. This is the only thing I've thought of, or been able to find. But it does not work as expected. You can select "Custom Selections" and it does indeed clear all of the section selections, but then you can't select any of the sections.

```
InstType /NOCUSTOM
InstType "Desktop"
InstType "Laptop"
InstType "Custom Selections"
!define Desktop 1
!define Laptop 2


Section "Theme" Theme
    SectionIn ${Desktop} ${Laptop}
    ; ...
SectionEnd

Section "Hibernate" Hibernate
    SectionIn ${Desktop}
    ExecWait 'powercfg /change /monitor-timeout-ac 15'
    ExecWait 'powercfg /change /hibernate-timeout-ac 180'
SectionEnd

; More sections
```

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457916/how-to-make-sure-all-components-are-deselected-when-using-componentsonlyoncusto

Answer (score 0):

The custom type is special and is used when no other InstTypes matches the current selection. To get what you want you have to use a little hack:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles
InstType "Desktop"
InstType "Laptop"
!define Desktop 1
!define Laptop 2

Section "Theme" Theme
SectionIn ${Desktop} ${Laptop}
SectionEnd

Section "Hibernate" Hibernate
SectionIn ${Desktop}
SectionEnd

!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Sections.nsh
!macro HACK_GetUpdatedCurInstType ret tmp
FindWindow ${tmp} "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem ${tmp} ${tmp} 0x3F9
SendMessage ${tmp} ${CB_GETCURSEL} 0 0 ${ret}
SendMessage ${tmp} ${CB_GETITEMDATA} ${ret} 0 ${ret}
!macroend

Function .onSelChange
!insertmacro HACK_GetUpdatedCurInstType $1 $0
Var /GLOBAL prevSelInstType
${If} $1 = ${NSIS_MAX_INST_TYPES} ; Custom
${AndIf} $1 <> $prevSelInstType
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Theme}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Hibernate}
${EndIf}
StrCpy $prevSelInstType $1
FunctionEnd
```